# Is it not necessary for a callback method to have a definition in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am new to node.js. I have been seeing code where a callback method is just called but it is never defined anywhere in the file. So without definition what does that call to the callback method do exactly? For example

```
CollectionDriver.prototype.findAll = function(collectionName, callback) {
this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) { 
  if( error ) callback(error);
  else {
    the_collection.find().toArray(function(error, results) { 
      if( error ) callback(error);
      else callback(null, results);
    });
  }
});
```

};

I understand that based on the success or failure of the this.getCollection(collectionName) method, the callback method "callback" is called appropriately, however there is no definition available for the callback method. So how is this call useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `callback` argument is passed when `findAll()` is called.  It is up to the caller to define it appropriately and pass a reference to it.  This is a characteristic of Javascript, so it's not just node.js.

You should see something like this in the calling code:

```
var driver = new CollectionDriver(...);
driver.findAll("foo", function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // process results here
    }
});
```

Here, the callback is defined by the caller and passed to the `findAll()` method.

---

It also doesn't have to be an inline function definition like above.  The caller could also be like this:

```
function findCallback(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // process results here
    }
}

var driver = new CollectionDriver(...);
driver.findAll("foo", findCallback);
```

In either case, you're passing a reference to a function to `.findAll()` which it calls when it completes.

Comment: I understand this that when the function completes it calls the callback method which can be inline or separately defined. You also have provided the appropriate definition for it. However, if you look at my example, there the callback method is just called as either callback(error) or callback(null,results) and there is no definition available for it. So is it ok for me to not define the callback everyrtime and also what is the use of this explicitly calling the callback method when we know that it will be called once the function is done.

Comment: @AbhishekChauhan - I don't understand your comment here. The callback is called only at runtme when `.findAll()` is executing. At that point in time, it's value comes from the argument passed to `.findAll()`. That part is no different than the function using the argument `collectionName`.  Perhaps you don't understand that a function reference can be passed to a function and the receiving function can then call it.

Comment: I understand that we can call a method passed into another method as argument. But the point that I want to make here is that there is no definition for the callback method- neither at the place where the findAll() is called, nor at the place where it is defined (which is this code itself). So then what does the call to callback() do, if no definition is provided?

Comment: @AbhishekChauhan - it has to be defined by the caller and passed with the function like my two examples show.  Show us the code that calls this function successfully and I'll show you where it's defined. If no definition is provided by the caller and passed as an argument, then `.findAll()` will throw an error.

Comment: To clarify, the function that I have shown in my example is its definition, whereas what you have written is the definition of the callback function. Your function's actual definition will be somewhere else where it can also make any call to the callback method as they are made in my method. After the function ends, it will refer to the callback function definition which you have provided. Moreover, in my function two different signatures for callback method are there i.e. callback(error) and callback(null, results). Does this mean that we have two different definitions of callback.

Comment: @AbhishekChauhan - I've written how one calls the code you've written so you can see where the callback function comes from.  There is nothing wrong with the code you included.  It works.    The same function in javascript can be called with different arguments and it is up to the receiving function to look at what arguments are present.  If `err` is set, then the result argument will not be used, thus the caller doesn't even bother to send that argument.  Still same function, just called with one argument sometimes and two arguments sometimes.  That's legal in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks. Very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

`callback` is a parameter to `findAll` (`function(collectionName, callback)`!). You would use it like so:

```
// assuming `driver` is an instantiated `CollectionDriver`:
driver.findAll("collectionOfCows", function(error) {
  console.log("findAll called us back with", error);
});
```